# Is there a high quality image scaling library that does not use Java2D API?

Tags: java, image, image-scaling

I need a high scaling Image API in Java. But the algorithm of Java are to simple. I have evaluate some libraries like thumbnailator. But all this libraries that I have look at only add a framework around the Java2D API.

Answer (score 1):

There is `imagemagick` http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#java

From its site:

> ImageMagick® is a software suite to create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images. It can read and write images in a variety of formats (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF. Use ImageMagick to resize, flip, mirror, rotate, distort, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves.

Comment: There is only a Java wrapper to native API. This required to save the image as file, call the native API and load the image again. The next problem is that it not run on any platform.